# Error starting service in Wildly 24 with JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am new to wildfly and we currently use it to host Fileserver services on a AWS ec2 instance.
It was all working fine while we were testing until we re-ran the build script a few times.
After building the ec2 servers around 5 times, it was all working fine. However, on the 6th build without changing anything, we are getting the below error and i cannnot figure out whats going on.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"FileServer.ear\".\"brs.indexingservice-web-2.0.0.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processingQueue' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [brs.indexingservice.support.PersistentQueue]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processingQueue' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [brs.indexingservice.support.PersistentQueue]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processingQueue' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [brs.indexingservice.support.PersistentQueue]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [brs.indexingservice.support.PersistentQueue]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"}}
```

Comment: You issue lies in brs.indexingservice.support.PersistentQueue constructor

Comment: Thank you,  you were right. the file used by the constructor was corrupted. Deleted the file and it recreated the file. It is all working now. Thank you so much.